# Help with analyzing data with multiple variables

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am looking for the best way to represent data from a survey I conducted in a statistical form. Basically, I am looking to compare if the participant was familiar with the salamander species 'hellbender' (Familiar vs. Unfamiliar), the see how likely the participant was to believe the species would bite, be poisonous, be detrimental to native species, and be detrimental to the river. Additionally, I wanted to see if the participants education level influenced this. I have made tables that total all of this information, but now am stuck on how to best present this data. Any help would be truly appreciated, statistics is definitely not a strength of mine.

[image: Example of my data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can visualize your data. You might communicate your findings better using graphs instead of showing four separate frequency tables. Here are some ideas:

Using two tables on the left (e.g., hellbender bite tables), I recreate part of your data. So, you have three variables, namely, *level of education* (ordinal variable with 7 categories, but the first one is empty), (likelihood of) *Hellbender bite* (again ordinal, likert-like item, 5 categories), and *familiarity* (binary variable). First, you want to know whether familiarity with the species makes a difference for the belief in the likelihood of hellbender bite.

You can create a bar plot for each category of the *familiarity* using *Hellbender bite*. I share the `R` code just in case:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

dataset %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Familiarity, fill=Hellbender)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette = "Oranges") +
  labs(x=" ", y=" ") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Hellbender Bite")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Please note that this graph uses cell percentages. You can also use counts, or as in the following example, the percentage distributions within the categories of *familiarity* (changing the code to `position="fill"`):

[image]

Now, these graphs give us some idea. For instance, the percentage of respondents reporting hellbender bite is unlikely is higher among those who are familiar with the species compared those who are unfamiliar. But instead of just eyeballing the graphs, you might want to test (e.g., using $\chi^2$ test of association) whether there is an association between these two variables.

What about the influence of education? We can incorporate information from the education variable into our graph. Here is one way to do that:

```
dataset %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Education, fill=Hellbender)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~Familiarity) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette = "OrRd") +
  labs(x=" ", y=" ") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("High\nSchool", "Some\nCollege", 
                              "Associate\nDegree","Bachelor's\nDegree",
                              "Master's\nDegree", "Doctorate")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Hellbender Bite"))
```

[image]

On the x axis, we have categories of the education level now, but the graph has somewhat limited usefulness. We can tweak it a little further:

```
dataset %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = reorder(Education, desc(Education)))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Hellbender), 
           position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FEF0D9", "#FDCC8A", 
                             "#FC8D59","#E34A33","#B30000"), 
                    name="Hellbender Bite",
                    labels=c("Very unlikely", "Somewhat unlikely",  
                             "Average risk","Somewhat likely",
                             "Very likely"))+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x=" ", y=" ")+
  facet_grid(~Familiarity)
```

[image]

It does not tell us a detailed story, but across the categories of education (except high school), only a small portion of the respondents familiar with the species report average and higher risk of Hellbender bite (you can tell a little more looking at these graphs, but one should be wary of over-interpretation).

However, it seems like you ask about something more: How does the relationship between familiarity and belief in the likelihood of hellbender bite vary by education? Now, it is hard to show whether such a variation exists using graphs and tables. So, you might want to model these relationships by including an interaction effect. But that also means going beyond reporting descriptive statistics.

Comment: You are a saint, thank you so much! I am taking this all in, and I hope to add some of this to my thesis. I am not too familiar with R, I have been doing everything in Excel, so if I have trouble with R, I hope you wouldn't mind if I followed up with a question. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Aurie I'm glad I could help. I'll do my best to answer your questions on `R`. But I am sure there ways to create these plots in Excel and other software.